# GeckoDriver Selenium; desired capabilities error

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I am using Selenium using Geckodriver and Selenium-3.3.1.  Whenever I run my tests I keep getting this FirefoxDriver error.  Does anybody know the cause or meaning for this?

```
1491438811062   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:41173
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'ANDY-PC', ip: '192.168.0.6', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
    at selenium.WebDriver_Singleton.getInstance(WebDriver_Singleton.java:16)
    at selenium.Core.<init>(Core.java:32)
    at selenium.Core.main(Core.java:46)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide Firefox Binary location. Check out this link on how to set it up.

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/